# Cannot able to increment row count in every year

Tags: php, mysql

I want to restrict user to upload 50 photos per year. Say for example user can upload 50 photos in 2015 and after that user gets error message. Again in 2016 user can able to upload 50 photos but the photo which user uploads in 2015 will not be deleted.

This is my upload.php

```
<?php
// set timeout period in seconds
$inactive = 100;
// check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($session_life > $inactive)
        { session_destroy(); header("Location: logout.php"); }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
include "lib/connection.php";
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    //die ("Access Denied");
    header("location:index.php?msg=Please login with valid credentials");
}
if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
 { 
     include "lib/top.php";
include "lib/left.php";

?>


            <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="dashboard.php">Home</a></li>                    

                    <li class="active">Upload Photo</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <?php
            if(!empty($_GET['msg'])) {
    $message = $_GET['msg'];
    print "$message";

            }
    ?>
                 <div class="block block-fill-white">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h2>Upload Photo</h2>
                    </div>
                    <FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="pic-db-upload.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="content controls">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">Title:</div>
                            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" required placeholder="Enter some Title"/></div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">Description:</div>
                            <div class="col-md-9"><textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" required></textarea></div>
                        </div> 
                        <?php
$sel="SELECT * FROM  `category`";
$tab=mysql_query($sel);
                        ?>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">Category:</div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <select class="form-control" name="category" required>
                                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                                    <?php
                                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tab))
{

                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['cname']; ?></option>
                                    <?php
}
                        ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">Thumbnail Height:</div>
                            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="theight" name="theight" required placeholder="Enter height"/></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">Thumbnail Width:</div>
                            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="twidth" name="twidth" required placeholder="Enter width"/></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">File:</div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="input-group file">                                    
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                                    <input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" required/>
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Browse</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>     
                          <div class="form-row">
                          <div class="col-md-3">   </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9" style="align:midle">
                          <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="UPLOAD">
                            </div>
                        </div>                       
                    </div>
                </div>               
                </form>

            </div>



        </div>
        <?php
        include "lib/bottom.php";
 }
        ?>


and this is my insert query

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); 
ob_start();
include("lib/connection.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    //die ("Access Denied");
    header("location:index.php?msg=Login with valid credentials");
}
if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
 { 

//======================= INSERT =================================================

if($_POST[submit]=="UPLOAD")
  {
if($_POST[title]!="" && $_POST[category]!="" && $_POST[description]!="" && $_FILES[picture][name]=="")
  {
    header("location:upload-photo.php?msg=You have not inserted any picture ");
  }
 else
 {

$resource = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM album");
$count = mysql_result($resource,0);

if ($count < 50)
     {
//======================== THUMBNAIL CODE ======================== 
function thumb($a,$b)
{
    $image_path=$a;
    $new_width=$_POST[twidth];
    $new_height=$_POST[theight];
    $thumb_path=$b;
    $ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$image_path)));
    if($ext=='jpg'||$ext=='jpeg'||$ext=='gif'||$ext=='png')
    $img=@imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
    else
    die("only jpg or jpeg or gif or png format supported");
    $width=imagesx($img);
    $height=imagesy($img);
    $tmp_img=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
    imagecopyresized($tmp_img,$img,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$width,$height);
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagejpeg($tmp_img,$thumb_path);
}

//==================================================================

$p=md5(rand(1,1000));
$pict=$p.".jpg";
$target_path1 = "big_pic/big_".$pict;
copy($_FILES[picture][tmp_name],$target_path1);
$target_path2="thumb_pic/thumb_".$pict;
thumb($target_path1,$target_path2);

$ins = "INSERT INTO `album`(`id`,`date`,`title`,`description`,`cid`,`picture`,`thumbnail`,`default`)VALUES('',now(),'$_POST[title]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[category]','$target_path1','$target_path2','$pict')" ;
mysql_query($ins);
header("location:upload-photo.php?msg=Photo successfully uploaded");
     }
     else
     {
header("location:upload-photo.php?msg=Sorry maximum number of photo uploaded. Please contact system administrator");
     }
     }
}

//======================= END INSERT =================================================
}
 ?>
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: miantain databaase. check registering year and keep count of uploaded photos per users. Also keep urls of photos in separate table so you can easily delete all photos if year change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query to only count the photos in the current year:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM album WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Comment: thank you this worked                                                      $date=date('Y');
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM album WHERE `year`='$date'");
$count = mysql_result($resource,0);

if ($count < 500)

Comment: I don't see why you need to use the PHP variable to get the year, when MySQL can do it perfectly well by itself.